# Do you get more money if you choose a higher difficulty?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

You can choose to increase the difficulty before a mission in GTA Online, which corresponds to a 1.5x multiplier of RP. But does it also increase the amount of money obtained ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't. There was a rumor about an increase in cash loot (+25% for medium, +50% for hard etc.). However this has been proven false several times. I tried this out with a friend on Nervous Ron. The money amounts stayed the same.